# How to control which Screen a Window is shown in from QML

Tags: qt, qml

My application has a main window with a button, and when I click the button I use `createComponent` to create a subclass of `Window {}` and show it (purely in QML). I am running the application on my macbook with another monitor attached.

If I do not attempt to set the `.x` or `.y` properties of my new window, then it is shown on top of my main window, whether the main window is on my macbook's screen or on the attached monitor (i.e. the new window is always shown on the same screen as the main window). However, if I do set the `.x` or `.y` properties of the new window (to any value at all), then the new window is always shown on the macbook screen, regardless of which screen I have my main window on.

How can I control which available screen my new Window is shown in? And related, how can I exactly control the positioning of the new window in the screen (for example, how can I have the new window always appear in the lower-right corner)?

Edit: basic code. **RemoteWindow.qml**:

```
Window {
    id: myWindow
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint 
        | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint
    modality: Qt.NonModal
    height: 500
    width: 350

    // window contents, doesn't matter
}
```

In my main window, I have this function (`remoteControl` is a property that keeps a reference to the remote window):

```
function showRemoteWindow() {
    remoteControl.x = Screen.width - remoteControl.width
    remoteControl.y = Screen.height - remoteControl.height
    remoteControl.show()
}
```

Also on my main window I have a button, and in its `onClicked:` event I have this code:

```
if (remoteControl) {
    showRemoteWindow()
} else {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("RemoteWindow.qml")
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        remoteControl = component.createObject(parent)
        showRemoteWindow() // window appears even without this call,
            // but calling this method to also set the initial position
    }
}
```

If I comment out the setting of `.x` and `.y` in the showRemoteWindow function, then my RemoteWindow always appears in the same screen as my main window (either the macbook screen or the attached monitor). But if I leave those two lines uncommented (or make any other attempt to set the x or y position of the window), then my RemoteWindow *always* appears on the macbook screen, regardless of which screen my main window is in.

Comment: I've dealt with these issues before in Qt.  Multi-monitor is nuts. Can you share your code, preferably as a minimal viable complete example?

Comment: @selbie: added my basic code snippets. Sorry, the app I'm working on (legacy code) is enormous and it's difficult to disentangle individual parts of it.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Which version of Qt do you use ? In Qt 5.9 they added a [`screen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#screen-prop) property on `Window` that might do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Like @Blabdouze said, there is now in Qt 5.9 a [`screen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#screen-prop) property for `Window`.
You can assign it an element of the [`Qt.application.screens`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#application-prop) array.

If you want to display a window in the first screen you can do :

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.3 // the 2.3 is necessary

Window {
    //...
    screen: Qt.application.screens[0]
}
```

Assigning a screen to a window seems to position it at the center of the screen.
If you want to finely control the window's position, you can use `x` and `y` instead of `screen`. For example if you want to display a window in the bottom left of the first screen :

```
Window {
    //...
    screen: Qt.application.screens[0] //assigning the window to the screen is not needed, but it makes the x and y binding more readable
    x: screen.virtualX
    y: screen.virtualY + screen.height - height
}
```

If you are not on Qt 5.9 yet, you could expose the screens array from c++ like so :

```
QList<QObject*> screens;
for (QScreen* screen : QGuiApplication::screens())
    screens.append(screen);
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("screens", QVariant::fromValue(screens));
```

And access the geometry of a screen with [`geometry`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#geometry-prop)/[`virtualGeometry`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#virtualGeometry-prop) instead of `virtualX`/`virtualY` :

```
x: screens[0].geometry.x
```

Comment: Note the coordinates are (usually) for the corner of the content. If setting y to the top, the frame might be outside the window. Unless you set `y` to 0, in which case it will be automatically moved to `y = frameHeight`...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go. The hack (I mean that as a complement) for exposing the screens if I'm not on Qt 5.9 is incredibly helpful. My company is currently building its apps with Qt 5.6 and upgrading Qt is a painful bureaucratic process.